# Best way to find the amount spent in the First 24 hours after joining in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I was trying calculating the amount purchased by all the user in the first 24hrs after joining. I have log details of every user with all the timestamp values in it.

This is how the table looks like:

```
User_id  item   amount  logtime
    123  item1  1.99    2017-09-01 11:34:43
    123  item1  1.99    2017-09-02 11:39:43
    123  item2  2.99    2017-09-03 11:39:43
    123  item3  4.99    2017-09-04 13:02:02
    123  item1  1.99    2017-09-05 14:19:40
    123  item2  2.99    2017-09-06 01:09:03
    345  item1  1.99    2017-09-08 11:45:03
    345  item1  1.99    2017-09-08 17:01:03
    345  item1  1.99    2017-09-09 10:11:03
    345  item1  1.99    2017-09-09 15:15:03
    345  item1  1.99    2017-09-10 11:45:03
    345  item1  1.99    2017-09-11 00:35:12
```

And the join date for all the users:

```
User_id   Join_datetime
123       2017-09-01 11:34:43
345       2017-09-08 11:45:03
```

Required result

```
User_id   First_24_hrs_amount
123       1.99
345       5.97
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work

```
SELECT "User_id", SUM(amount) AS "First_24_hrs_amount"
FROM log
 JOIN user USING("User_id")
WHERE logtime < "Join_datetime" + '24 hours'::interval
GROUP BY "User_id"
```

You didn't specify table names so I used `log` and `user`.